# How to call a result from a function in another one in R

Tags: r, function, extract

can please somebody tell me how I can call my output which are two matrices as an input into another function?

```
X1=function(y,z)
{
 output1=y*z
 output2=y/z
}

X2=function(p,q)
{
 input=X1(y,z)
 input1=input$output1    ??? How to specify the output that I can call it this way? output1 and output2 are matrices!
 input2=input$output2
 equation=input1+input2
}
```

I tried `return()` and `data.frame` but both didn't work. Any tipps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `c` as some might otherwise expect because you'll lose the structure of the matrices.  Instead, use `list` when you want to return multiple objects from an R function.

```
X1 <- function(y,z)
{
 list(
  output1=y*z,
  output2=y/z
 )
}
```